# Maven on Jenkins Only Pulls from Remote Repo

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

Any help information would be greatly appreciated. I have a maven project that I need to build. It comes with a *.jar in the lib directory that I need to install first and add it to the local repo.

On Jenkins, subsequent build attempts ("clean install" or "clean package") fail.

I install the jar with:
*mvn install:install-file -Dfile=filename.jar -DgroupId=group -DartifactId=artifact -Dversion=version# -Dpackaging=jar*

This adds the dependency to /var/lib/jenkins/.m2/repository.

But during subsequent builds ("clean install" or "clean package"), this repository is never referenced in the stacktrace. Instead, I get:
*Could not find artifact group:artifact:jar:#.# in AsposeJavaAPI (https://repository.aspose.com/repo/)*

I wonder if anyone has an idea of what could be causing this? Jenkins obviously can identify the local repo, but it fails whenever there is read, rather than a write, attempt.

Jenkins ver. 2.222.4
Maven Integration 3.6 Plugin

Thank you for any help that can be provided.

Comment: Is your build of the second maven project just using a command line script? Or some maven plugin?   If the latter possible the plugin is using a different local .m2 repo?

Comment: I'm using the plugin both times. For "install:install-file" and for regular "install". And in the same project. I use them in the "Goals and options" section of a maven project. I just edit the project after the first command has put the dependency in .m2.

Comment: Hmm. That is strange. The only thing I could suggest is trying the same steps manually on the command line either on the Jenkins server as the jenkins user or from your own machine to see if it uncovers some issue that is being hidden through the plugin.

Comment: Trying it in the execute shell now. Turns out the command line only wants to look at the remote repo.